# Type mapping for int[] to List<int>

Tags: java, c++, swig

I managed to generate a Java class from my C++ implementation. For this I have a `SubwordEncoder.i`:

```
/* File : example.i */
%module encoder

%{
#include "SubwordEncoder.h"
%}

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "SubwordEncoder.h"
```

Where interface looks like this:

```cpp
class SubwordEncoder {
public:
    int* encode(char* decoded);
    char* decode(int* encoded);
};
```

The generated code comes our like this:

```java
public class SubwordEncoder {
  private transient long swigCPtr;
  protected transient boolean swigCMemOwn;

  protected SubwordEncoder(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SubwordEncoder obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        encoderJNI.delete_SubwordEncoder(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_int encode(String decoded) {
    long cPtr = encoderJNI.SubwordEncoder_encode(swigCPtr, this, decoded);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_int(cPtr, false);
  }

  public String decode(SWIGTYPE_p_int encoded) {
    return encoderJNI.SubwordEncoder_decode(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_int.getCPtr(encoded));
  }

  public SubwordEncoder() {
    this(encoderJNI.new_SubwordEncoder(), true);
  }

}
```

But is is possible to also get `List<Integer>`, `ArrayList<int>`, `Iterable<int>` or something similar from SWIG?

`char*` already gets converted to a Java `String` (from the [docs](http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Doc/Manual/Java.html#typemaps_c_to_java_types)) but what's the simplest way to extend these mappings?

SWIG version is 4.0.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you willing to change your C++ code? Using an iterator in C++ instead of a pointer opens lots more options. Also https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/std_vector.i is related in that it shows how to use autobox typemaps that you'll need here.

Comment: Oh, one more question: with that interface how does one know the length of the arrays?

Comment: @Flexo Definitely. I only used `char*` because this automatically converts the datatype to a Java String. But I can't seem to get a `List<int>` or something like that from a `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<int>::iterator` .. :/

Comment: @Flexo Do I have to set `std_vector.i` explicitly somehow?

Comment: It's also weird that only `char*` gets converted to a Java `String` but it's not the case for `std::string`

Comment: `std::string` are converted to Java `String` if you use the file "std_string.i" : http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Library.html#Library_std_string

Comment: @Fifi Ah, thank you. Will try that tomorrow. I saw you commented on another question of mine. I was able to fix it it was just a pathing issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change this interface and make use of C++ containers (or itereators/ranges, but that's a little less well supported in SWIG). As of SWIG 3.1 (or maybe 4.x?) both `std::vector` and `std::list` should implement sensible Java interfaces and autobox primitives correctly. So your interface could become this:

```
class SubwordEncoder {
public:
    std::vector<int> encode(const std::vector<char>& decoded);
    std::vector<char> decode(const std::vector<int>& encoded);
};
```

Which you can then wrap with this:

```
/* File : example.i */
%module encoder

%include <std_vector.i>

%{
#include "SubwordEncoder.h"
%}

%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;
%template(CharVector) std::vector<char>;

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "SubwordEncoder.h"
```

This does two things. Firstly it pulls in the SWIG library support for `std::vector`. Secondly it uses `%template` to tell SWIG to explicitly instantiate and wrap the vector template using two types. These are given sensible names inside Java.

With that in place it should be pretty straightforward to achieve what you're trying to do here safely.

The caveat being that automatic conversions from `byte[]`, `int[]` or another Java collection won't happen to the function inputs automatically. It would be possible to create an interface that did this if that behaviour was important/useful to you, but it would require a fair few more typemaps and JNI calls.

Comment: Happy to go down the Iterators/collections/array inputs route if that's useful for you.